# How to prove that the Z3 group satisfies the associative law using Z3-SMT-LIB

Tags: z3

I am trying to prove that the Z3 group satisfies the associative law using the following Z3-SMT-LIB code

```
(set-option :mbqi true)
(declare-sort S)
(declare-fun f (S S) S)
(declare-const a S)
(declare-const b S)
(declare-const c S)
(assert (forall ((x S) (y S))
            (= (f x y)  (f y x))))
(assert (forall ((x S))
            (= (f x a) x)))
(assert (= (f b b) c))
(assert (= (f b c) a))
(assert (= (f c c) b))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(declare-fun x () S)
(declare-fun y () S)
(declare-fun z () S)
(assert (not (=> (and (or (= x a) (= x b) (= x c)) (or (= y a) (= y b) (= y c)) 
                  (or (= z a) (= z b) (= z c))) 
            (=  (f x (f y z)) (f (f x y) z)))))
(check-sat)
```

The corresponding output is

```
sat 
(model 
;; universe for S: 
;; S!val!1 S!val!0 S!val!2 
;; ----------- 
;; definitions for universe elements: 
(declare-fun S!val!1 () S) 
(declare-fun S!val!0 () S) 
(declare-fun S!val!2 () S) 
;; cardinality constraint: 
(forall ((x S)) (or (= x S!val!1) (= x S!val!0) (= x S!val!2))) 
;; ----------- 
(define-fun b () S S!val!0) 
(define-fun c () S S!val!1) 
(define-fun a () S S!val!2) 
(define-fun f ((x!1 S) (x!2 S)) S 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!0) (= x!2 S!val!0)) S!val!1 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!0) (= x!2 S!val!1)) S!val!2 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!1) (= x!2 S!val!1)) S!val!0 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!1) (= x!2 S!val!0)) S!val!2 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!0) (= x!2 S!val!2)) S!val!0 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!2) (= x!2 S!val!0)) S!val!0 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!2) (= x!2 S!val!1)) S!val!1 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!1) (= x!2 S!val!2)) S!val!1 x!1))))))))) 
 ) 

 unsat
```

Run this example online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tWFSA)

The questions are:

1. Is this proof correct?
2. There is a more elegant proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every group must satisfy the associativity axiom. I guess you are trying to prove that every model for the first block of assertions satisfy the associativity axiom. To complete the example, we should also prove the inverse element axiom.

To prove these two properties, we can use the following commands:

```
(push)
;; prove the inverse axiom
(assert (not (forall ((x S)) (exists ((y S)) (= (f x y) a)))))
(check-sat)                
(pop)

(push)
;; prove the associativity axiom
(assert (not (forall ((x S) (y S) (z S)) (= (f x (f y z)) (f (f x y) z)))))
(check-sat)                
(pop)
```

Z3 cannot prove them. However, it succeeds if we assert that that we are only interested in models of size at most 3.

```
(assert (forall ((x S)) (or (= x a) (= x b) (= x c))))
```

[Here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/5oUd) is the complete example.

Comment: It is possible to use the same strategy in models of size at most 4?.  Im am trying with Z4 but the output is `timeout`