# Sort name issue in Z3

Tags: z3

In a previous post [Z3 group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431326/how-to-prove-that-the-z3-group-satisfies-the-associative-law-using-z3-smt-lib)  some group axioms were proved using a sort named S to represent the group. Please run the code  [code with sort named S](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/5oUd)  But now when the name of the sort is changed to G the code does not work. Please look the issue on line [code with sort named G](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/I5V3)  It is necessary to use the name S for the sort or it is an issue of Z3? Please let me know.

Comment: Strange, but this seems local to the web version and the timeout we impose. Running your examples locally poses no problems.

Comment: I am trying to run the examples locally:  the example when the sort is named S runs very fast and generates the correct output; but the example when the sort is named G runs very slow and it does not stop.  Can you tell me what happens?

Comment: In my Ubuntu box using Z3 version 4.3.1, I could run the code using the name S in 4 seconds, but running the code using the name G didn't yield any result after 15 minutes.

Comment: Using Z3 unstable version (commit  d548c51a984ea3baf173c55dd57418bccb327b7c) I **couldn't** reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

A simplified version of the issue.

```
$ z3 -version
Z3 version 4.3.1
```

Using the name S:

```
$ cat S.smt 
(declare-sort S)
(declare-fun f (S S) S)
(declare-const a S)
(declare-const b S)
(assert (= (f a a) a))
(assert (= (f a b) b))
(assert (= (f b a) b))
(assert (= (f b b) a))
(check-sat)

;; Restrict the search to models of size at most 2.
(assert (forall ((x S)) (or (= x a) (= x b))))

;; Associativity
(assert (not (forall ((x S) (y S) (z S)) (= (f x (f y z)) (f (f x y) z)))))
(check-sat)

$ z3 -smt2 S.smt
sat
unsat
```

Using the name G:

```
$ cat G.smt
(declare-sort G)
(declare-fun f (G G) G)
(declare-const a G)
(declare-const b G)
(assert (= (f a a) a))
(assert (= (f a b) b))
(assert (= (f b a) b))
(assert (= (f b b) a))
(check-sat)

;; Restrict the search to models of size at most 2
(assert (forall ((x G)) (or (= x a) (= x b))))

;; Associativity
(assert (not (forall ((x G) (y G) (z G)) (= (f x (f y z)) (f (f x y) z)))))
(check-sat)

$ z3 -smt2 G.smt
sat
unknown
```

Comment: It is very interesting and worthwhile to note that it is not necessary to generate a model with the aim to prove the axiom.

Answer (score 0):

Please let ne know if the following code with the sort named G is correct.  Many thanks

```
(declare-sort G)
(declare-fun f (G G) G)
(declare-const a G)
(declare-const b G)
(declare-const c G)
(assert (forall ((x G) (y G))
            (= (f x y)  (f y x))))
(assert (forall ((x G))
            (= (f x a) x)))
(assert (= (f b b) c))
(assert (= (f b c) a))
(assert (= (f c c) b))
(check-sat)
(get-model)

(push)
;; prove the left-module axiom
(assert (not (forall ((x G)) (= (f a x) x ))) )
(check-sat)
(pop)

(push)
;; prove the right-module axiom
(assert (not (forall ((x G)) (= (f x a) x ))) )
(check-sat)
(pop)


(declare-fun x () G)
(declare-fun y () G)
(declare-fun z () G)

(push)
;; prove the right-inverse axiom
(assert (not (=> (and  (or (= x a) (= x b) (= x c)))   (exists ((y G)) (= (f x y) a)))))
(check-sat)                
(pop)

(push)
;; prove the left-inverse axiom
(assert (not (=> (and  (or (= x a) (= x b) (= x c)))   (exists ((y G)) (= (f y x  ) a)))))
(check-sat)                
(pop)

(push)
;; prove the associativity axiom
(assert (not (=> (and (or (= x a) (= x b) (= x c)) (or (= y a) (= y b) (= y c)) 
                  (or (= z a) (= z b) (= z c))) 
            (=  (f x (f y z)) (f (f x y) z)))))

(check-sat)  
(pop)    

(push)
;; prove the commutative property
(assert (not (=> (and (or (= x a) (= x b) (= x c)) (or (= y a) (= y b) (= y c))) 

            (=  (f x y ) (f y x )))))

(check-sat)  
(pop)
```

and the corresponding output is the expected

```
sat unsat unsat unsat unsat unsat unsat
```

Please run this code online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/ebW9)

Comment: If this is the code you are currently using, please add it to the question itself not as an answer. Thank You!